# Magento 2 require blocking all links

Tags: magento2.2.2

All links in my Magento 2 store just suddenly stopped working. If I remove the top require, it works:

```
var require = {
        "baseUrl": "https://2f44f.mojostratus.io/static/version1564697154/frontend/Mgs/default/pt_BR"
    };
```

What might be the issue? I haven't added any big change lately, only added a js file to the cart (which is working fine).

Comment: This is the base url, don't delete this. Check file permission for pub/static

Comment: what is url code return like 404 or etc ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was that one plugin was somehow binding to all document clicks and preventing default.

```
$(document).on('click', $.proxy(this.hidePopup, this)); // bind hide popup event
```

What is not resolved is why this started to be an issue, as it originally was fine.

Theme is Claue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can add more details and accept your answer. Good luck for your journey here.